# Without binarysearch,how can I do a search in matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

As I told in the title,how can I do that in Java ? Is that possible ?

Comment: With a linear search (for example, iterating the matrix with a loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[][] matrix = new int[sizeX][sizeY]

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        //do matrix processing here with matrix[i][j]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am new around here so that I don't know ask questions in a proper way.

Comment: No problem! We were all new here once (I've only been a member for 18 days). Did this solve your question? If so please feel free to upvote/accept my answer. This will give you a better approval rating which will persuade others to answer your questions in the future.